# Monaca error - Failed to get the project information

Tags: monaca

I use the debugger IOS, and always displays the error: **Failed to get the project information.**

I have to keep opening and closing the monaca mobile and kit location, lose much time on it.

Does anyone know how to fix this? Thank you.

Comment: Does this happen just in a specific project or in all the projects?

Comment: I have only one project

Comment: please open a support ticket here: https://monaca.mobi/en/support/index

Comment: Monaca is resolve in APP IOS